# Very wide and long table in latex?

Tags: latex, longtable

There are several ways to split long tables over several pages in latex (e.g. longtable, supertabular). If the table is still to wide, using sidewaystable or lscape can be used.

However, I have a long and wide table and I have not found a way to implement it in my document (well, other than manually making it fit).

This can't be so uncommon and there should be a way around it?

Comment: This would probably fare best on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you please post at least one sample line of such table?